# How can I load a variable as a jTextField display text

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am very new to java, and have tried to create a form in NetBeans 7.4 that will take a variable called "name" and use it as the display name for a jTextField.  I have tried many things, and this is as close as I can get (doesn't work, but I get no errors).  Would you please review the code and help me see what I am missing.
class StatusScreen extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
public StatusScreen() {                         // Creates new form StatusScreen
    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    PartName = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
            formWindowOpened(evt);
        }
    });

    PartName.setEditable(false);
    PartName.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    PartName.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(PartName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 380, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(PartName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 54, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(235, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
    setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
}                                 

//public static void main(String args[]) {                      //This is here for class testing.
public void showStatusScreen(final String name){                //This is program entry point.
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(StatusScreen.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(StatusScreen.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(StatusScreen.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(StatusScreen.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {            //To create and display the form
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new StatusScreen().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {            //Trying to initialize the PartName field with String name (not working)
  @Override
  public void run() {                                           //Trying to initialize the PartName field with String name
     PartName.setText(name);                                    //Trying to initialize the PartName field with String name
  }                                                             //Trying to initialize the PartName field with String name
```

});
    }

```
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JTextField PartName;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: Go through the Swing Tutorials and learn to do this by hand.  The time it takes to learn how to do this will payoff in the long run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things to fix :

- You don't need two threads to run the application and then another to set the text. Do both at one place
- `PartName` is a field in the `StatusScreen` class. Therefore, you need to create an instance of `StatusScreen` and have a setter method which will call upon `PartName.setText(name)`. You cannot call a field of another class without an instance of it.

Include below in the main method:

```
StatusScreen ss = new StatusScreen();
ss.setVisible(true);
ss.setPartName(name);
```

`setPartName` method would be something like :

```
public void setPartName(String name){
    PartName.setText(name);
}
```

Comment: Wow.  Thank you very much.  I have been trying different options from web (and stack overflow) searches all weekend to try and get this working.